# Parse array list to array (SimpleEntry)

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I am trying to parse a generic array list to an array using standard methodology, but an error throws when converting an Object list to SimpleEntry list. Here is my code:

```
// Start with ArrayList of simple entries
AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<E, Integer>[] entries = (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<E, Integer>[] ) new Object[arraylist.size()];
// Fill array with AL elements
```

What is the issue with this?

The error is as follows:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.AbstractMap$SimpleEntry;
```

Comment: Can you post all your code? What else do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Considering what you posted, you will have a list at the end, maybe this will help you:

```
        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<E, Integer>[] entries2 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry[arr.size()];

        // or this      
        SimpleEntry<E, Integer>[]  entries =  new SimpleEntry[arr.size()];
```